# Error: Undefined name 'FOLDERID_ProductFavorites'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How to fix this error?

../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/path_provider_windows-2.2.1/lib/src/folders.dart:79:41: Error: Undefined name 'FOLDERID_ProductFavorites'.
static String get ProductFavorites => FOLDERID_ProductFavorites;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/dghub/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1350
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/home/dghub/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             11.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1